# Unable to display image using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

net code as follows

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img1" ImageUrl="~/Images/important.gif" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="print" />
```

and my javascript is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printIt() {
        var win = window.open('', 'Image', 'resizable=yes,...');
        if (win) {
            //var imgID = '<%= img1.ClientID %>';
            var imageControl = document.getElementById('<%=img1.ClientID%>').src;
            win.document.write(imageControl);
            win.document.close();
            win.focus();
            win.print();
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

// updated code as per `vitoshabg` answer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printIt() {
        var win = window.open('', 'Image', 'resizable=yes,...');
        if (win) {
            //var imgID = '<%= img1.ClientID %>';
            var imageControl = document.getElementById('<%=img1.ClientID%>').src;
            win.write('<img src="' + imageControl + '">');
            //win.write(imgParent);
            win.document.close();
            win.focus();
            win.print();
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

But instead of the image I am getting the url can some one help me to get the image here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var imageControl = document.getElementById('<%=img1.ClientID%>').src;`

Here you get the 'src' attribute of the element returned by getElementById.

You can create the new image with

`win.document.write('<img src="' + imageControl + '">');`

Comment: No luck for this too empty space is getting instead of image

Comment: You have to keep this `imageControl = document.getElementById('<%=img1.ClientID%>').src;`.

Comment: Thanks I missed this `win.document.write`

Comment: Yeah instead `document.write('<img src="' + imageControl + '">');` we have to use `win.document.write('<img src="' + imageControl + '">');`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the URL because you have `.src` on the end of this line:

```
var imageControl = document.getElementById('<%=img1.ClientID%>').src;
```

Change it to this to get the image control:

```
var imageControl = document.getElementById('<%=img1.ClientID%>');
```

Comment: I tried this too but this is just giving as follows `[object HTMLImageElement]`

Answer (score 0):

Bug removed ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printIt() {
        var win = window.open('', 'Image', 'resizable=yes,...');
        if (win) {
            //var imgID = '<%= img1.ClientID %>';
            var imageControl = document.getElementById('<%=img1.ClientID%>');
            win.document.write(imageControl);
            win.document.close();
            win.focus();
            win.print();
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this too but this is just giving as follows `[object HTMLImageElement]`